# How to disable GIFs from being entered in Android EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, gif, android-inputtype

How can I shut down the possibility for the user to insert GIFs in `EditText`?
I tried to switch different `inputTypes`, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I don't think EditText will allow to enter a GIF into it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko if you will click on a GIF into EditText it will be shown it's URL like that: "https://media0.giphy.com/media/NbXTwsoD7hvag/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e475bfbf00a656e367649ae4741"

Comment: ok, so that is not a GIF, but an URL.

Comment: it is selected GIF's URL. The point is that I want to disable for the user this possibility, to enter its URL.

Comment: URL is just a text. If you have a pattern of how to determine if the text is an URL (it is quite easy) - add a textWatcher, and remove the URL from the EditText in it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thank you for your indications, it worked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's my solution for the question. Adding a textwatcher and checking if it contains the beginning of the URL. The user can still see the GIFs, but cannot enter one. Maybe it's not the best solution, but it works.

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(View view, Editable s) {
            if (view.getId() == R.id.edittext) {
                if(s.contains("https://"){
                    editText.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The URL of the GIF / Sticker is not entered into the text field. The keyboard sends a ACTION_SEND intent.

Comment: That fails i think if user manually entered a url like user want to add url in Editext then it fails